# What is the best interface circuitry for using FSR sensors?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, sensor, circuit-design, interface

Force Sensitive Resistor (FSR) is a sensor which lowers its resistance when there is force upon it. If there is no force acting on it, the resistance is ~10MOhms.

Looking at Interlink's guide ([here](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Pressure/fsrguide.pdf)) and FlexiForce's A401 datasheet ([here](https://www.tekscan.com/sites/default/files/resources/FLX-%20A401-%20B.pdf)) here are interface circuits which are recommended:

**1- Simple Voltage Divider**
Pros: simplicity
Cons: ADC impedance introduces distortions in measurements

**2- Voltage Follower via OpAmp (buffer)**
[image: Buffer]
Pros: Input resistance of OpAmp is near-infinite
Cons: There is offset error due to OpAmp

**3- Adjustable Buffer**
[image: adjustable buffer]
Pros: Gain and offset can be tweaked
Cons: Rather complex,IMO

**4- Transimpedance Amplifier**
Pros: Conductance/Force of FSR seems to be more linear that Resistance/Force
Cons: ???
[image: transimpedance amplifier]

Note that there is a **limit on the current** flowing through FSRs. The circuit should also take that into account.

**1-** Are there any other circuits for this application?
**2-** What is the best configuration for (A) Calibration and (B) Normal Use?

Here are my other questions related to FSRs:
[What is meant by "adjustment of the output gain and offset" of a Force Sensitive Resistor interface circuitry?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279038/what-is-meant-by-adjustment-of-the-output-gain-and-offset-of-a-force-sensitive)
[What is the maximum force that a FSR sensor can detect?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281640/what-is-the-maximum-force-that-a-fsr-sensor-can-detect)

FSR sensors have both creep and hysteresis. That is one issue. The other issue is a good interface circuit which both limits the current and produces zeros offset and noise.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a wheatstone bridge with either differential amplifier or even special wheatstone bridge amplifier. Take a look here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slyp163/slyp163.pdf